# Writing-out numbers in mandarin till 19999 algorithm

Tags: mandarin, number

My current task includes writing-out numbers in different languages, also mandarin. I have never grappled with mandarin but I checked several resource and tested my algorithm to the best of my believe. But to really make sure that everything works fine I would highly appreciate a second look of a native speaker. Since I don't know any native speakers I came to this place looking for help.

My algorithm can be accessed here: https://codepen.io/f16r/pen/xvrwOx
It is intended to work from 0 to 19999.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Good job, the grammar is correct and it works well.

Comment: I second that, works fine! The result seems to have line breaks after thousands, then after hundreds. Is that intentional? Maybe that comes from "write.innerHTML = result.replace(/,/g, '<br>');" the <br>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm have to handle 0 between first and last digits as well. Insert 零 for those cases.

For example,

> 10003 should be 一萬零三.
>
> 10301 should be 一萬零三百零一.
>
> 30028 should be 三萬零二十八.
>
> 41009 should be 四萬一千零九.